# How can I check that a class constructor is called with proper attributes in Sinon?

Tags: javascript, tdd, sinon

I'm testing code that instantiates an object from an external library. In order to make this testable, I've decided to inject the dependency:

Boiled down to:

```
const decorator = function (obj, _extLib) {
  var ExtLib = _extLib || require('extlib')
  config = determineConfig(obj) //This is the part that needs testing.
  var el = new ExtLib(obj.name, config)
  return {
    status: el.pay({ amt: "one million", to: "minime" })
    bar: obj.bar
  }
}
```

In my test, I need to determine that the external library is instantiated with the proper `config`. I'm not interested in whether this external library works (it does) nor wether calling it, gives results. For the sake of the example, let's assume that on instantiating, it calls a slow bank API and then locks up millions of dollars: we want it stubbed, mocked and spied upon.

In my test:

```
it('instantiates extLib with proper bank_acct', (done) => {
  class FakeExtLib {
    constructor(config) {
      this.acct = config.bank_acct
    } 
    this.payMillions = function() { return }
  }

  var spy = sandbox.spy(FakeExtLib)
  decorator({}, spy) // or, maybe decorator({}, FakeExtLib)?
  sinon.assert.calledWithNew(spy, { bank_acct: "1337" })

  done()
})
```

Do note that testing wether e.g. `el.pay()` was called, works fine, using spies, in sinon. It is the instantiation with `new`, that seems untestable.

To investigate, let's make it simpler even, testing everything inline, avoiding the subject under test, the `decorator` function entirely:

```
it('instantiates inline ExtLib with proper bank_acct', (done) => {
  class ExtLib {
    constructor(config) {
      this.acct = config.bank_acct
    }
  }

  var spy = sandbox.spy(ExtLib)
  el = new ExtLib({ bank_acct: "1337" })
  expect(el.acct).to.equal("1337")
  sinon.assert.calledWithNew(spy, { bank_acct: "1337" })
  done()
})
```

The `expect` part passes. So apparently it is all called properly. But the `sinon.assert` fails. Still. Why?

How can I check that a class constructor is called with proper attributes in Sinon?" Is `calledWithNew` to be used this way? Should I spy on another function such as the `ExtLib.prototype.constructor` instead? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close.

In the case of your simplest example, you just need to create `el` using the `spy` instead of `ExtLib`:

```js
it('instantiates inline ExtLib with proper bank_acct', (done) => {
  class ExtLib {
    constructor(config) {
      this.acct = config.bank_acct
    }
  }

  var spy = sandbox.spy(ExtLib)
  var el = new spy({ bank_acct: "1337" })  // use the spy as the constructor
  expect(el.acct).to.equal("1337")  // SUCCESS
  sinon.assert.calledWithNew(spy)  // SUCCESS
  sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(spy, { bank_acct: "1337" })  // SUCCESS
  done()
})
```

(Note that I modified the test to use `calledWithExactly` to check the arguments since `calledWithNew` doesn't seem to check the arguments properly in v7.2.2)